# How I can add function on data to add images

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Hi**, I can't add my images on my view by from a array
I use Vue.JS on Laravel project !

I use spell my component and data function:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    data: () => {
        return {
            products
        }

    }
} ];
```

my array "product":

```
const products = [
{
    id: 1,
    description: 'Montre Tissot noire',
    price: 12,
    img: './resources/img/tissot-noire.jpg'
},
{
    id: 2,
    description: 'Montre Samor noire',
    price: 16,
    img: './resources/img/samor.jpg'
}];
```

on my HomeComponent.vue:

```
<div v-for="product in products">
        <img v-bind:src="product.img" v-bind:alt="product.description">
</div>
```

Comment: what error u r getting .? have u checked your image is present in those location ?

Comment: i havn't error and my image link is good ^^

Comment: then .? what is issue

Comment: my vuejs devtools don't be read my data function => products and when i spell it on my component vuejs don't be read it